# How to count subviews in Super View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one class in which i have two method _addView() and _removeView().

And these method i am using in another class for adding view and removing view but its not working.If i am using in the same then its working.

For Remove-

```
- (id)deleteBoxAtIndex:(int)boxIndex{      
    for (int i = 0; i < [[self subviews] count]; i++ ) {
        [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:boxIndex] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then how i count the subviews in that class or remove from that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to the `UIView` instance (the one that has got the `subview`s) to the other object so that you can call:

```
 myView.subviews
```

I don't know if this could work for you:

```
- (id)deleteBoxAtIndex:(int)boxIndex fromView:(UIView*)view {      
  for (int i = 0; i < [[view subviews] count]; i++ ) {
    [[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:boxIndex] removeFromSuperview];
  }

  return self;
}
```

If you give more detail about the relationship between the two classes you mention (basically, the names and how one interact with the other), I could give you more hints.

Answer (score 8):

You correct in trying to use `[self.subviews count]` to count the number of subviews, but there is an elegant way to remove all subviews from a view in Objective-C. Try this:

```
[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem not in retrieving the count but in fact that your relay on a count that changes dynamically inside of your for loop logic execution. Do cleanup of subviews in the following way:

```
while([[self subviews] count] > 0) {
    UIView *view = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the superview property:

```
[[self superview] subviews]
```

to do the similar loop you are doing right row. However I'd strongly encourage you to use

```
[[self superview] viewWithTag:boxIndex]
```

instead of objectAtIndex: method

Answer (score 0):

Just do a loop of all subViews u want to remove:

```
for (UIView *subs in [self.view subviews]){
    [subs removeFromSuperview];

}
```